# FbProphet model gives TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, time-series

Hi I'm trying to generate a time series forecasting model using python FbProphet model. I'm getting the following error during its implementation. Following is the error I received.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        36     f14.set_figheight(5)
>        37     f14.set_figwidth(15)
>   ---> 38     fig = model_prop.plot(forecast, ax=ax14)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py
>   in plot(self, fcst, ax, uncertainty, plot_cap, xlabel, ylabel)    1520
>   return plot(    1521             m=self, fcst=fcst, ax=ax,
>   uncertainty=uncertainty,
>   -> 1522             plot_cap=plot_cap, xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel,    1523         )    1524
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\plot.py in
>   plot(m, fcst, ax, uncertainty, plot_cap, xlabel, ylabel, figsize)
>        68         fig = ax.get_figure()
>        69     fcst_t = fcst['ds'].dt.to_pydatetime()
>   ---> 70     ax.plot(m.history['ds'].dt.to_pydatetime(), m.history['y'], 'k.')
>        71     ax.plot(fcst_t, fcst['yhat'], ls='-', c='#0072B2')
>        72     if 'cap' in fcst and plot_cap:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py in
>   inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1853                         "the
>   Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.**name**),    1854
>   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
>   -> 1855             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1856     1857         inner.**doc** = _add_data_doc(inner.**doc**,
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py
>   in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)    1526     1527         for line in
>   self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
>   -> 1528             self.add_line(line)    1529             lines.append(line)    1530
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py
>   in add_line(self, line)    1930
>   line.set_clip_path(self.patch)    1931 
>   -> 1932         self._update_line_limits(line)    1933         if not line.get_label():    1934             line.set_label('_line%d' %
>   len(self.lines))
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py
>   in _update_line_limits(self, line)    1952         Figures out the
>   data limit of the given line, updating self.dataLim.    1953
>   """
>   -> 1954         path = line.get_path()    1955         if path.vertices.size == 0:    1956             return
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in
>   get_path(self)
>       949         """
>       950         if self._invalidy or self._invalidx:
>   --> 951             self.recache()
>       952         return self._path
>       953
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py in
>   recache(self, always)
>       650         if always or self._invalidx:
>       651             xconv = self.convert_xunits(self._xorig)
>   --> 652             x = _to_unmasked_float_array(xconv).ravel()
>       653         else:
>       654             x = self._x
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook__init__.py
>   in _to_unmasked_float_array(x)    2048         return np.ma.asarray(x,
>   float).filled(np.nan)    2049     else:
>   -> 2050         return np.asarray(x, float)    2051     2052
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in
>   asarray(a, dtype, order)
>       536 
>       537     """
>   --> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>       539 
>       540
>
> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'datetime.datetime'

Following is the code that I tried out

```
for i in Brokers:
    series2=TimeSeriesData[TimeSeriesData.BrokerName == b][['Gross_Premium']]
    series2['ds']=Broker_Clusters.index
    series2['y'] = series2.Gross_Premium
    series2=series2.drop('Gross_Premium',axis=1)
    series2['ds'] = series2['ds'].apply(str)

    #divide into train and validation set
    train = series2[:int(0.7*(len(series2)))]
    test = series2[int(0.7*(len(series2))):]

    model_prop=Prophet() 
    model_prop.fit(train)
    forecast = model_prop.predict(test)
    # Plot the forecast
    f14, ax14 = plt.subplots(1)
    f14.set_figheight(5)
    f14.set_figwidth(15)
    fig = model_prop.plot(forecast, ax=ax14)
```

Following is my test dataset

```
                             ds             y
Date                                         
2016-03-15  2016-03-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2016-04-15  2016-04-15 00:00:00  180534.47230
2016-05-15  2016-05-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2016-06-15  2016-06-15 00:00:00    2545.12000
2016-07-15  2016-07-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2016-08-15  2016-08-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2016-09-15  2016-09-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2016-10-15  2016-10-15 00:00:00   20637.88000
2016-11-15  2016-11-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2016-12-15  2016-12-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2017-01-15  2017-01-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2017-02-15  2017-02-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2017-03-15  2017-03-15 00:00:00    8878.08000
2017-04-15  2017-04-15 00:00:00  198174.32710
2017-05-15  2017-05-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2017-06-15  2017-06-15 00:00:00    3458.61875
2017-07-15  2017-07-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2017-08-15  2017-08-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2017-09-15  2017-09-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2017-10-15  2017-10-15 00:00:00    5159.47000
2017-11-15  2017-11-15 00:00:00       0.00000
2017-12-15  2017-12-15 00:00:00       0.00000
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried adding the following right before `plot()` call

```
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
```

and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `type` of the date column you have. In your case, it is a string and supposes to be a timestamp.

Instead:

```
series2['ds'] = series2['ds'].apply(str)
```

Use:

```
series2['ds'] = list(map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x), series2['ds']))
```